# provider LOCALE_ID with useFactory returns null

Tags: angular, angular9

After update to angular 9 my provider returns null.

```js
@NgModule({
    providers: [
        [...],
        {
          provide: LOCALE_ID,
          deps: [TenantService],      // some service handling global settings
          useFactory: (tenantService) => tenantService.currentTenantValue.language // returns locale string
        }
    ]
})
```

My service:

```
public currentTenant: Observable<Tenant>;

constructor() {
    this.currentTenantSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Tenant>(null);
    this.currentTenant = this.currentTenantSubject.asObservable();
}

public get currentTenantValue(): Tenant {
    return this.currentTenantSubject.value;
}
```

I believe it is something with the observable and the provider is taking the first state of the variable before receiving the language value that comes through an `httpClient.get`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set it as default in the app.module

```
{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'en-US' }
```

And in my shared.module I defined it again with the language coming from the server

```
export function tenantServiceFactory(tenantService: TenantService){
  return tenantService.currentTenantValue.language;
}

    {
      provide: LOCALE_ID,
      deps: [TenantService],      //some service handling global settings
      useFactory: tenantServiceFactory  //returns locale string
    },
```